# Limiting My Friends List

Tags: facebook

I would like to restrict a friend from seeing other friends of mine unless they are mutual friends.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.facebook.com/put_your_username_here/friends > Edit Privacy > Friend List > Custom > Don't share this with